# Keeping pest deterrant device running during power outage

Tags: charger

I have a holiday home in a remote area subject to frequent power outages. I use pest repelling devices powered from 9 Volt mains adaptors but when an outage occurs the little furry rascals rush inside and create havoc. Can I rig up a 9 Volt charger and battery and connect the load in parallel so the battery takes the load during outages. I have heard of chargers which provide a power path but can only find them for industrial use and very expensive.

Comment: How much current does the device use, and how long do the outages usually last?

Comment: Why not just get 12 V pest repelling devices (these exist and are very cheap) and use a 12 V car battery attached to a maintenance charger that is hooked up to mains power?

Comment: As far as I understand, all such repellents eventually become ineffective due to acclimatization of the pests.

Answer (score 2):

### The $1 solution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDMd2h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### How it works:

AC/DC output voltages tend to be a little higher than rated and batteries tend to be a little bit lower. The 2-diode wired-or configuration means that the higher voltage supply will "win" (sourcing most of the current to the device).

That means the AC power supply will provide the device power when available, but after the voltage falls (no AC power available), the battery will take over and provide power.

The advantages of this configuration are that it's cheap, easy to make, and make-before-break (there is never a point where power is interrupted while switching over). The disadvantages are that it's not the most efficient possible solution due to the voltage losses in the diodes.

Comment: Crossed my mind, too, before writing my short comment. But I didn't recommend it because accessing a 9 V battery system that will run the pest devices for weeks or months is not nearly as easy as doing the same with 12 V lead acid systems (or built up with 2 V forklift cells.) Plus, maintenance "float" chargers are also easily acquired and will keep the battery system charged when power exists. I'd just rebuy the pest devices, myself, and use standard farm units spec'd at 12 V lead-acid battery inputs. Less worry about "forgetting" to check the charge on the battery system.

Comment: @jonk -- Of course I agree that's a better solutioN. Was just trying to keep in the spirit of the question (9V, cheap, hobbyist-level).

Answer (score 0):

How long are the power outages?  Are you sure the problem isn't that the pest repellent doesn't work?  Unless you are talking about outages lasting weeks at a time, I think it is much more likely that your pest repellent is not effective than that squirrels are waiting outside your house for the noise to stop so they can rush inside.

Anyway, since you didn't provide power or runtime requirements, I recommend using a standard computer UPS and plug the 9V adapter into that.  With such a light load, it should last quite a while.  If you provide more information on your requirements there may be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the helpful ideas. I particularly like the $1 diode solution. I don't think that my devices have yet become ineffective. My problem is mice and they only seem to invade when power is off. I visited the house in April for the first time since October 16. The first thing I found was a notice in my letterbox advising me that for maintenance purposes power would be shut off for eight hours on a date in February. I then found that there had been a short rampage through the kitchen but no further and no ongoing presence. This suggests that they came in as soon as the repellers stopped and vacated when they resumed. On a previous occasion two years ago I discovered on arrival that due to a fallen cable power had been off for an extended period. That time they had really done a number on the place. Chewed cushions and bedding. Even chewed my antenna cables. I use three small domestic devices which seem to be enough when powered but they need to be live even when the house is occupied so rigging up 12 Volt batteries is not practical. What about my first thought. Using 9 Volt Li-Ion batteries while being simultaneously trickle charged. The devices use less than 200mA.e